# Query can't find column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to make this query work for the last couple of hours, but I can't.  So I hope someone can help.

Here's the error:
**Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'network_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `networks`.* FROM `networks` WHERE (network_id = 1,2)**

Here are my models:

```
class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :user_network_relations

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :network, :dependent=>:destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :network

class UserNetworkRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :network
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :network
```

controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user_approved = UserNetworkRelation.find(:all,:conditions => ['user_id = ? and status =? ', @user, "approved"])
@networks = Network.find(:all,:conditions => ['network_id = ?',@user_approved])
@user_networks = Customer.find(@networks)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
@networks = Network.find(:all,:conditions => ['network_id = ?',@user_approved])
```

You are explicitly telling ActiveRecord that you want to restrict the column `network_id` which obviously doesn't exist. Probably you meant the `id` column. The correct line could read as follows:

```
@networks = Network.where(:id => @user_approved).all
```

or equivalently

```
@networks = Network.where('id = ?', @user_approved).all
```

Note that in my example, I used the new ActiveModel / AREL syntax of Rails 3. You used the deprecated (but still supported) Syntax of Rails 2. You should switch to the new syntax as it allows you to chain queries which is mightier and much more readable. See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) on how to use the new AREL syntax.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  was it wrong for me to use .find?  for example, if i did Network.find(:id => @user_approved).all would that have worked?  THANK YOU!

Comment: That would have worked as well. But as I said above, the `.find` method from ActiveRecord 2 is deprecated. You should use the new AREL syntax instead.